# React Native | Function to setState

Tags: react-native, hook, use-state

My problem is simple. I want to send the setState operation to the function and do it there. My function is called "Input". Automatic keyboard closes after entering one letter in its current state. It doesn't work properly.

Goal: I want to do the setState operation by sending it to another function.

```
const [ex, setEx] = useState();

const Input = ({value, setValue}) =>  (
        <TextInput
            onChangeText={text => setValue(text)}
            value={value}
        />
);

return (
    <Input
        value={ex}
        setValue={setEx}
    />
)
```

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to do the setState operation by sending it to another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place Input component outside like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';

const Input = ({value, setValue}) => {
  return (
    <TextInput
       value = {value}
       onChangeText={text => setValue(text)}
    />
  )
}
    
const MyComponent= () => {
  const [value, setText] = React.useState('');

  return (
    <Input value={value}
        setValue={setText}/>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Finaly. I congratulate you for your attention. Thank you very much for taking a case. Happened.